# Programming C# Navier Stokes Modeling

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I just started C# programming Navier Stokes model for 3D visualized compressible fluid liquid/gas properties management of gasket-plate heat exchanger models of my company. In reality, I can't even understand the equations themselves because of unidentified PDE/tensor notations. My background is undergraduate level chemical engineering and elementary calculus and introductory linear algebra with senior level programming skill. Does anybody recommend any best approach/steps to accomplish this project from scratch. I would like to do it in 1.5 years. I found too many subjects/textbooks out to study many.

Comment: Are you using specialized computational fluid dynamics software? Accurate 3D fluids simulations (even without compressibility and heat exchanging) are among the most challenging computational problems present in science. Most of the tools used in industry were developed by teams of people over multiple years or even decades. I would highly advise against developing such a tool from scratch, even if you had the proper background.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!. I agree that, so I need some real-world understanding of the equation first, and next I will combine 3rd party libraries. I have no insight yet how to understand the equation itself and how to choose pretty reasonable 3rd party tools. Any idea too for the suitable CFD tools out there ?

Comment: "An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics" by Batchelor will be a good starting point. He also has a book on Computational Fluid Dynamics, but it does not contain some modern techniques.

Comment: Thanks again, also, Could you recommend any CFD software product good for my application ? I found some in Matlab but looks not suitable for my product.

Comment: OpenFOAM is a common starting place but for actual production-level CFD work most good tools are either propriety or export controlled.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try my starting by OpenFOAM as you recommended, and after I get more insight, then I am willing to contract some production level package I don't know yet. My goal is full integration of Navier-Stokes modeling into my company's existing commercial product to get the value up.

Comment: My current software is utilizing just classical heat/fluid average-based equations. So, I need it to reasonable PDE/Tensor/Mesh based calculation, modeling and management.